# Make a modal/dialog appear after submitting an asp form

Tags: javascript, html, css, vb.net

I'm trying to make a modal of sorts appear after submitting a form on an ASP page (as a confirmation). I've tried calling a JavaScript function which should set the CSS on the `div` containing the modal to `display:normal` from its default in the CSS page which is `display:none`

I'm calling the JavaScript using `ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock` and I've put this call in the `btnSubmit_Click` code method after the `SendMailMessage` has done its thing.

The page does a postback after the form has done its thing and the confirmation div is nowhere to be seen.

Can anyone help?